# BindService is slow so service is still not connected when i want to use my service

Tags: android

My activity is implementing SurfaceHolder.Callback and also i am binding a service in onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
bindService(intentBind, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected in");
        retService= IReturnService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
```

In surfaceChange i am doing

```
public void surfaceChanged(..)
 if(retService!= null){
      retService.setSurface(..)
}
```

Problem is sometimes surfaceChanged is called before service bind is complete. In that case i am not able to do setSurface.

I know i can use flag and do retService.setSurface(..) in onServiceConnected after service is connected. But is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: There are ways to change the way these dependencies are expressed to make it nicer to read, but for the most part, you still have to check in both places to make sure all conditions are met before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

If `surfaceChanged` is called before service binding. You could do the binding when `surfaceChanged` called.

```
private Surface surface;

public void surfaceChanged(..)
   surface = .. // set the surface used on onServiceConnected
   if(retService != null) {
      retService.setSurface(..)
   } else {
      // bind service
   }
}
```

Then when the service bind successfully, set the surface in the callback `onServiceConnected`.

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected in");
    retService= IReturnService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    retService.setSurface(surface);
}
```

Comment: i know i can do it in onServiceConnected as i already mentioned, but i am asking is there any other way to do it

Comment: @sankyjain Didn't figure out a better solution so far, if someone has a better way, let me know it, thanks.